# Display Contentful Banner if Boolean is True - Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I have created a content model called "Announcement Banner". I want to show the announcement if "display" is set to true. I have been able to query it and display the banner on the page by just querying `{announcmentBanner}`.. but now I am trying to have it only display if the boolean is true (or set to yes)

I feel like I am on the right track. Here is what my content model looks like: [image: contentful content]

Below is my code:

```
const Header = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      contentfulCarousel(title: { eq: "homepage" }) {
        Images {
          id
          gatsbyImageData
          description
        }
      }
      contentfulAnnouncementBanner {
        bannerMessage
        display
      }
    }
  `)
  const announcementBanner = data.contentfulAnnouncementBanner.bannerMessage
  return (
    <>
    
   {
   announcementBanner.display && 
   <div className="announcementBanner">
   <h2>{announcementBanner.bannerMessage}</h2>
   </div>
  }
```

any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. The issue is in:

```js
 const announcementBanner = data.contentfulAnnouncementBanner.bannerMessage
```

You are getting `bannerMessage` while you whould get the parent node, `contentfulAnnouncementBanner`.

```js
 const Header = () => {
   const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
     query {
       contentfulCarousel(title: { eq: "homepage" }) {
         Images {
           id
           gatsbyImageData
           description
         }
       }
       contentfulAnnouncementBanner {
         bannerMessage
         display
       }
     }
   `);
   const announcementBanner = data.contentfulAnnouncementBanner;
   return (
     <>
       {announcementBanner.display && (
         <div className="announcementBanner">
           <h2>{announcementBanner.bannerMessage}</h2>
         </div>
       )}
     </>
   );
 };
```

Watch out, I don't know if it's because of a wrong copy-paste in the question, but you had a wrong formatting and syntax issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ferran ! That was very helpful. (Also what do you mean had a wrong formatting and syntax issue?